# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{n})}{n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Does the following series converge? 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{n})}{n}}$$

It shouldn't, but I have no idea how to prove it. I was wondering about **Integral Criterion**, but the assumptions are not satisfied. Or perhaps **Dirichlet** test would help, but then it should be shown that $\sum_{k=1}^n(\sin^2(\sqrt{k}))$ is bounded.

Comment: $\sum(sin^2(\sqrt k))$ is not bounded.  There exists a sub-sequence such thant every $k_n$ is nearly 1.

Comment: Use limit comparison test

Comment: I'm not sure if limit comparsion test helps. Function $\sin(x)$ can be compared with $x$ when $x$ tends to $0$. Here $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: This depends on the distribution of $\sin(n^{\frac12})$ within $[-1,1]$, but I can't find a relevant result right now.

Comment: One idea: determine the ranges for which $\sin^2(\sqrt{n}) \geq \frac{1}{4}$. Then estimate the sum of the terms that fall in this category. This should correspond to roughly $\frac{(2k-1/3)^2\pi^2}{4} < n < \frac{(2k+1/3)^2\pi^2}{4}$ where $k$ is an integer. There are roughly $\propto k$ terms which should sum to $O(1/k)$ which diverges.

Comment: Doesn't it still alternate in its own positive values still?

Comment: I was wondering whether you can apply the integral test here?

Comment: @Asker123 The lack of monotonicity is a problem when it comes to the integral test. However, if you look at tired's answer below, you will see that _asymptotically_, you could compare with an integral.

Comment: May I use integral test here(I am not sure about it!!!). If I can use, then clearly $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin^{2}{\sqrt{n}}}{n}$ does not exists

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Observe that $\sin^2(\sqrt{n}) \geq 1/4$ iff $|\sin(\sqrt{n})| \geq 1/2$ iff 
$$\frac{\pi}{6} + k\pi \leq \sqrt{n} \leq \frac{5\pi}{6} + k\pi$$
for some nonnegative integer $k$. This chain of inequalities is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + k\pi\right)^2 \leq n \leq \left(\frac{5\pi}{6} + k\pi\right)^2$$
For a fixed $k$, the number of values of $n$ which satisfy the above is approximately
$$\left(\frac{5\pi}{6} + k\pi\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\pi}{6} + k\pi\right)^2
= \frac{2\pi^2}{3} + \frac{4\pi^2}{3}k > 6+13k$$
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{n})}{n} > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6+13k}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{5\pi}{6} + k\pi\right)^2}$$
which diverges by limit comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Very nice. +1.${}$

Comment: Excellent in its simplicity and directness.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{n})}{n}$.

By the [Euler-MacLaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums) we have

$$
S_N\sim_{\infty}\int_1^N dx\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{x})}{x}+\mathcal{O}(1)
$$

You can show this by observing that the derivates of $\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{x})}{x}$ are $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^{1+m/2}}\right)$, where $m$ is the order of the derivative.

Performig a change of variables $x=y^2$ we get
$$S_N\sim_{\infty}2\int_1^N dx\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}+\mathcal{O}(1)\sim\log(N)+\mathcal{O}(1)
$$

which shows that the sum is unbounded.
The last asymptotic identity can be proved by using $\sin(x)^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$ combined with an integration by part.

Comment: Just a small comment, your formula for $\sin^2x$ in the end has a sign problem. Except that, I like that you use asymptotics and the Euler--Maclaurin formula.

Comment: This should also work for the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{n}}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @joseph yeah sure, this method is quiet flexible and worth knowing especially because it gives us not only the answer to ur question but also an asymptotic value for the sum.

Comment: @mickep, yepp u are right, thx for spotting and for the kind words. have a nice evening!

Comment: @tired Thanks, it was very helpful for me:)

Comment: May be interesting to you $$\int_1^N \frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{x})}{x}\,dx=-\text{Ci}\left(2 \sqrt{N}\right)+\text{Ci}(2)+\frac{\log (N)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k\in \Bbb N$ let $n_k=\lfloor (k+\frac12)^2\pi^2\rfloor$. Then $\sin^2 \sqrt n_k\approx 1$ and also $\sin^2 \sqrt {n_k+d}\approx 1$ for $0<d<\sqrt{n_d}$. This gives us $\approx k\pi$ summands of size $\approx \frac1{k^2\pi^2}$, i.e., a contribution of $\approx \frac1{k\pi}$. This allows us to compare with the divergent harmonic series.

While the "$\approx$" used in this argument should be made more explicit for a formal proof, we can be quite generous at this ...